# Result:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: asp.net-core

**I got this error when trying to populate the cascade drop-down list in my asp.core project. When I try to create a bike with my two cascade drop-down I got this error.**


 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().

```
 These are my Create Page Code-- Here MakeDDL My Master Table and BrandDDL is a Child table


    @using VroomFive.Extensions
     <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var MakeDDL = $("#Make");
                    var BrandDDL = $("#Brand");
                    BrandDDL.prop('disabled', true);
                    MakeDDL.change(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                            BrandDDL.prop('disabled', true);
                            BrandDDL.val("0");
                        }
                        else {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/api/brands/" + $(this).val(),
                                method: "get",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    BrandDDL.prop('disabled', false);
                                    console.log("Success:");
                                    BrandDDL.empty();
                                    BrandDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: '0', text: '--Select Brand--' }));
                                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                                        BrandDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: item.id, text: item.name }));
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="tblMakes">Make</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <select asp-for="tblBike.MakeId" asp-items="Model.tblMakes.ToSelectListItem()" class="form-control" id="Make"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="tblBike.MakeId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="tblBrands">Brand</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <select asp-for="tblBike.BrandId" asp-items="Model.tblBrands.ToSelectListItem()" class="form-control" id="Brand"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="tblBike.BrandId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue based on the existing code. Could you share the complete view code and backend code?

Comment: if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                BikeVM.tblMakes = _db.tblMakes.ToList();
                BikeVM.tblBrands = _db.tblBrands.ToList();
                return View(BikeVM);
            }
            _db.tblBikes.Add(BikeVM.tblBike);
            _db.SaveChanges();